Drools => org.kie.api.runtime.StatelessKieSession or org.kie.internal.runtime.StatelessKnowledgeSession
I am working on upgrading drools to 7.0.0 from drools 6.4.0. Currently I am using StatelessKnowledgeSession (which points to org.drools.runtime.StatelessKnowledgeSession from Knowledge-api.6.4.0.Final)
Below is the code
public StatelessKnowledgeSession stateMapppingKnowledgeSession(MyUtility myUtility) 
{
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    DecisionTableConfiguration config = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration();
    config.setInputType(DecisionTableInputType.XLS);
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("META-INF/drools/allRules.xls"), ResourceType.DTABLE, config);
    
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) 
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured.. " + kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
    }
    
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatelessKieSession knowledgeSession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
    knowledgeSession.setGlobal("myUtility", myUtility);
    
    return knowledgeSession;
}

I am now upgrading to drools 7.0.0 so based on documentation I have read online,
I have updated pom as below,
From
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

To
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

And other dependencies as below
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

Question: Most of documentation online says to use StatelessKieSession when upgrade to 7.0.0 but after upgrading to drools 7.0.0 I see reference of both StatelessKieSession (org.kie.api.runtime.StatelessKieSession) and also StatelessKnowledgeSession (org.kie.internal.runtime.StatelessKnowledgeSession).
I am not sure which one to use in my code [(1)use StatelessKieSession or (2) keep using StatelessKnowledgeSession and add reference of org.kie.internal.runtime.StatelessKnowledgeSession].
Really appreciate the suggestions or any pointers.

Do not use the internal package classes. They're not intended for public consumption, undocumented, and liable to change without warning. Some even disappear between minor releases.
